# Can I :split and go directly to a line?

Tags: split

I can open a file with vim on the command line like so:

```
vim fnord.txt +50
```

And it will take me to the 50th line

Is it possible to do the same thing with `:split`? So far I haven't been able to figure out how to do it.

- `:split fnord.txt +50`
- `:split fnord.txt ++50`
- `:split fnord.txt:50`

None of these work, and I didn't see anything searching for `line` within `:help split`.

Comment: `:h CTRL-W_F` could be also of use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are so close:

```
:split +50 fnord.txt
```

All commands in vim that create new buffer has prototype:

```
cmd [++opt] [+cmd] [file]
```

All commands in vim that write buffer to your disk has prototype:

```
cmd [++opt] [file]
```

[:h ++opt](https://vimhelp.org/editing.txt.html#%2B%2Bopt) is only used for special options that should be set before read or write a buffer.

```
:e ++fileformat=dos file
:e ++encoding=latin1 file
:e ++binary file
:e ++nobinary file
:e ++bad=?
:w ++enc=latin1 newfile
read ++edit file
```

Note the last `read ++edit file` change `'fileformat'` and `'fileencoding'` to values the same as `:e file`.

[:h +cmd](https://vimhelp.org/editing.txt.html#%2Bcmd) can be used to do any ex command:

```
:e +50 file
:e +/main file
:e +echo\ "blah\ blah" file
:e +setlocal\ textwidth=120 file
```

Comment: *perfect*! I figured there was something, and I was just missing it.

Answer (score 1):

`:split file | :50` should work, from command line.
The separator separate commands. A number typed as command  jumps to that line number.

Answer (score 0):

`vim [file] +50 +split` to split horizontally

`vim [file] +50 +vs`to split vertically

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question; it creates the appropriate split, but not the way the OP wants. I imagined OP started on file `a`, and then wanted to `:split b`, but have `b` be on the 50th line.

Comment: The question only specified one filename so I thought it wasn't about multiple files.